# TPL Dataflow create aggregated result array from all incoming nodes (multiple producer, 1 consumer)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Please note following code sample. I need an aggregator node, that can be linked to any number of sources, waites for all sources to send one message and then combines those in a result[].

This should be obvious and straigt forward, but somehow I do not find a solution.
I checked JoinBlock and TransformaterBlock, but both seem unfitting.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly uint _produceCount = 0;
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            BufferBlock<string> p1 = new BufferBlock<string>();
            BufferBlock<string> p2 = new BufferBlock<string>();

            // a block is required that accepts n sources as input, waits for all inputs to arrive, and then creates a result array from all inputs

            ActionBlock<string[]> c1 = new ActionBlock<string[]>((inputs) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', inputs));
            });

            p1.Post("Produce 1.1");
            p2.Post("Produce 2.1");

            // desired output:
            // "Produce 1.1, Produce 2.1"
            // actually the order is of no importance at this time

        }


    }
}
```

[Edit]
Further clarification:
I would like to have a block that:
- dynamically await all source-notes (at the point in time the first message arrives) to complete and aggregate the result to pass to follower nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a non-greedy `BatchBlock` for this. By being non-greedy each source will contribute one item to the batch. This was [originally suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13668329/7339946). And here's a tested example: 
Note as proof, `source1` is sent multiple items that don't show up in the batch:

```
public class DataAggregator
{
    private BatchBlock<string> batchBlock = new BatchBlock<string>(5, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions() { Greedy = false });
    private ActionBlock<string[]> writer = new ActionBlock<string[]>(strings => strings.ToList().ForEach(str => Console.WriteLine(str)));
    private BufferBlock<string> source1 = new BufferBlock<string>();
    private BufferBlock<string> source2 = new BufferBlock<string>();
    private BufferBlock<string> source3 = new BufferBlock<string>();
    private BufferBlock<string> source4 = new BufferBlock<string>();
    private BufferBlock<string> source5 = new BufferBlock<string>();

    public DataAggregator()
    {
        source1.LinkTo(batchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        source2.LinkTo(batchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        source3.LinkTo(batchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        source4.LinkTo(batchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        source5.LinkTo(batchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        batchBlock.LinkTo(writer, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task TestPipeline()
    {
        source1.Post("string1-1");
        source1.Post("string1-2");
        source1.Post("string1-3");
        source2.Post("string2-1");
        source3.Post("string3-1");
        source4.Post("string4-1");
        source5.Post("string5-1");
        //Should print string1-1 string2-1 string3-1 string4-1 string5-1
        source1.Complete();
        source2.Complete();
        source3.Complete();
        source4.Complete();
        source5.Complete();
        await writer.Completion;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
string1-1
string2-1
string3-1
string4-1
string5-1
```

Comment: This is working and practical. Let me anyhow add following minor note: I need to know the number of input blocks beforehand. I guess the bottom line is that there just is no aggregator block which is aware of all its sources. See also [q here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552291/aggregation-and-joins-inner-outer-left-with-tpl-dataflow?rq=1)

Comment: True there are limitations, even dynamically linking an unknown number of blocks would still leave you limited but, like the link describes, Rx can fill some of those gaps.

Comment: let me add that it is crucial to have one buffer block for each input source before the batch block - otherwise for example you have to sources in your network - one finishing completely before the other starts - you will get a pair of the first and the last item

Answer (score 2):

If you know your sources beforehand, I'd use a `JoinBlock` together with a `TransformBlock`. You would have to create a `BufferBlock` for each source.

First, the `JoinBlock` waits for one message from each source and packs them in one tuple. Then the `TransformBlock` creates a result array from the intermediate tuple.

If you do not know your sources beforehand, you need to explain how you expect your new block to know when to produce a result. That logic should then be put into a custom block, probably in the form of a `TransformManyBlock<string,string[]>`.

If you want to join a dynamic number of sources, you can create an unlimited join block like this:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var source1 = new BufferBlock<string>();
    var source2 = new BufferBlock<string>();
    var source3 = new BufferBlock<string>();
    var aggregator = CreateAggregatorBlock( 3 );
    var result = new ActionBlock<string[]>( x => Console.WriteLine( string.Join( ", ", x ) ) );
    source1.LinkTo( aggregator );
    source2.LinkTo( aggregator );
    source3.LinkTo( aggregator );
    aggregator.LinkTo( result );

    source1.Post( "message 1" );
    source2.Post( "message 2" );
    source3.Post( "message 3" );

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static TransformManyBlock<string, string[]> CreateAggregatorBlock( int sources )
{
    var buffer = new List<string>();
    return new TransformManyBlock<string, string[]>( message => {
        buffer.Add( message );
        if( buffer.Count == sources )
        {
            var result = buffer.ToArray();
            buffer.Clear();
            return new[] {result};
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<string[]>();
    } );
}
```

This assumes your sources produce messages at the same rate. If that's not the case, you need to but the identity of the source next to the message and have a buffer for each source.

Comment: A `JoinBlock` has a limited number of input sources. The OP is asking about having many sources, presumably more than any one `JoinBlock` can handle.

Comment: As you noted the sources must be in lock step for this to work since you're just taking the first three inputs and creating a race. Also, if this block operates in parallel then there's nothing protecting the shared buffer. Rolling your own variant of this block is not going to be a trivial task.

Comment: I guess I like the batch block more, indeed. I wasn't aware of the `Greedy=false` behavior, that's really two different blocks in one.